# Is there any third party library for Grid View in iOS?

Tags: ios, gridview

I am developing an iOS app (commercial use).

I want to present my content in GridView. I do understand there is UICollectionView.
However, I want to know if there are some third party library with nice UI and Animation.

It is better be free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try KKGridView talked about here:

http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/open-source-high-speed-interactive-ios-grid-view-component

With GitHub here:

https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView

Answer (score 0):

there is GMGridView and AQGridView those are the only 2 grid codes i know of